# R - Replace Multiple Ocurrences of character by only one . REGEX

Tags: r, regex, string, replace, special-characters

I have the following String

```
str<-"Actividades   Financieras && Bancarias #### 23"
```

I would like to remove multiple spacing, multiple && and multiple #. I'd like to get:

```
Actividades Financieras & Bancarias # 23
```

So far i have tried

```
gsub("[^A-z0-9]+"," ",string)
```

and i get

```
"Actividades Financieras Bancarias 23"
```

And it removes all # and &.

Is it there a way to keep one single character.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
string <- "Actividades   Financieras && Bancarias #### 23"
gsub("([#&\\s])\\1+", "\\1", string, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "Actividades Financieras & Bancarias # 23"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZDyDb/1) and an [online R demo](http://rextester.com/BBPIH91252).

**Details**

- `([#&\\s])` - Capturing group 1 matching a `#`, `&` or whitespace
- `\\1+` - a backreference to Group 1 value matching it 1 or more times (due to `+` quantifier).

The match is replaced with a single occurrence of the captured character (`\1` placeholder references Group 1 value from the replacement pattern).